# Move focus from one EditText in a layout to another EditText in another layout

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, focus, android-linearlayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV2eX.png)

I'm building this app and I'd like the user change the focus of the EditTexts with Next button of softkeyboard, like the picture
but it just move the focus all the way down for the first column
I used

```
android:nextFocussForward
```

with the desired id of EditText but it didn't work(nextfoucusleft/right/up/down didn't work)

It contains a parent  vertical Linear Layout
each row is Horizontal Linear Layout

here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/header"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/ecrit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/orale"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/lecture"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cells"
       >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ecrit1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/orale1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/lecture1"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cells"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/ecrit2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/orale2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/lecture2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cells"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ecrit3"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/orale1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/orale1"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/orale1"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/orale1"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/orale1"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/orale3"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/lecture3"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/result"
       >
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/header"
        >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/examen_ecrit"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/examen_orale"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/examen_finale"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cells"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/ecritFinal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/oraleFinal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/finaleFinal"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/header"
        android:text="@string/classactivity"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"/>
    <TextView
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/result"
        android:text="@string/zero"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/header"
            android:text="@string/finalgrade"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"/>
        <TextView
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_label"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/result"
            android:text="@string/zero"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `android:imeAction = "actionNext"`  with `android:nextFocussForward`.

Comment: Are you sure is `android:imeAction="actionNext"`? Probably you mean `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`.